# Why my application does not start ( with hibernate search configuration)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I want to use Hibernate Search to make full text search on JPA entities. I have configured with :

```
# Specify the DirectoryProvider to use (the Lucene Directory)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem

# Using the filesystem DirectoryProvider you also have to specify the default
# base directory for all indexes (make sure that the application have write
# permissions on such directory)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /var/lucene/indexes/data
```

I created manually the directory /var/lucene/indexes/data and i give 777 rights to data directory

When i start my application, i have the following error :

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize directory provider: com.mycompany.myapp.domain.JobOffer
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:212) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:99) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:261) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    ... 124 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: /var/lucene/indexes/data for index com.mycompany.myapp.domain.JobOffer
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:255) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:237) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:66) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
    ... 127 common frames omitted
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:57) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:74) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:374) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:150) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:148) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1f480bc4' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1f480bc4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.mycompany.myapp.domain.JobOffer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ............
```

Comment: Looks ok. Hardy to tell why the app cannot create the directory. I'd put a breakpoint into`DirectoryProviderHelper` and see whether you get some more information when you step through the directory/file creation.

Answer (score 1):

Please check ownership of the folder. change the ownership to appropriate user.